# How to prevent crust forming during frying, baking and grilling?

Tags: crust

I do not like the crust that forms on the surface of meat when frying, baking and grilling.  It seems to me this is caused by oil being on the surface of the meat.  In the case of baking and grilling I imagine oil comes out of the meat, sits on the surface and fries the surface temporarily hence there is some frying going on here.
1. Would I be correct in thinking this is the cause of the the crusty exterior, if not what causes it?

2. In all cases how can I avoid the crust from forming?  I have bought grilled chops from the shop and they did not have a crusty surface so there must be some way to avoid it? At the moment I'm just cutting the surface off and eating the interior.

Answer (score 4):

When you buy grilled meat from a store, it has been sitting in a fridge for some time, the crust will get less crusty because of the release of humidity from the meat.

You could do it at home, grill some chops, refrigerate them for a couple of hours, the crust will be "gone" (at least become less crusty).

If you want less crusty meat, you could roast the meat at lower temperature, or braise the meat or poach it.